# Wall opening - drywall corners

Tags: drywall, walls, plaster, patching-drywall

Our kitchen has an opening that used to have a bulky wood frame/shelves. We have removed that and now evaluating how best to repair the wall so it could be evenly painted and are thinking of adding a nice solid piece of varnished wood at the bottom.

The sides have a gap between the wall and the vertical opening. It looks quite large, too much to simply plaster over as it would probably just go and fall in.

What would be the best way to fix this? Would drywall tape and then plaster be enough? If I plaster, do I need anything special for plaster? I usually use the quick dry stuff to repair holes and have never done one that big.

Also, the yellow stuff seems to be only plaster, should I use what's there and add plaster to even it out/sand or am I better breaking what's there and starting over? I am not sure why there's a metal corner on one side and not the other.

[image: Upper corner]

[image: Bottom corner]

[image: Edge]

[image: Bottom]

Comment: Are you familiar with the term cased opening?

Comment: Stuff some [backer Rod](https://www.homedepot.com/p/M-D-Building-Products-1-2-in-x-20-ft-Caulk-Backer-Rod-71480/202066515) in the vertical gap before filling.

Comment: @Kris I am not no. Edit: ok yes I read your post, very similar to what I want minus the sides/top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the look of a cased opening with a bottom board incorporated to resemble a window sill on both sides

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's an opening like that yes. I am thinking of adding a board at the bottom, but would like to leave the sides/top as a "regular" wall corners / drywall+paint

Comment: You need drywall corners in a few places, then. I'm personally fond of the metal corner/ paper covered ones, because you don't need to work so hard at getting them nailed up. If you choose to do a stool/apron at the bottom, just cover up the hole; otherwise, I'd cut more drywall away and install a bit of plywood as backing for totally new rock. (My suspicion is that most of what you have at the bottom has been broken up a little.)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xdK2bSenaCA.   Finishing this type opening with mud on corner beads

Comment: @Kris super, thanks for the link. I found his channel earlier but had not found that particular video/knew search terms.

Comment: @Kris - gave up on the drywall idea, started a case opening this evening. Thanks for the helpful advice

Comment: @jfrobishow  hope it turns out great!